# visual studio, build configuration: how to make a build configuration that is based on another

Tags: visual-studio, build

I wish to add a new build-configuration to by C# visual studio project. I would like it be be like the debug build-configuration, but with one difference. I would like it to always be like the debug configuration even when the debug configuration changes.

How do I do this?

Comment: which visual studio version?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012
Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Professional

Visual C# 2012   04938-004-0033001-02995
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for using different preprocessor definitions. You'll have to manually edit the project file. I suggest you do this in VS itself since it has syntax highlighting and autocomplete for it.
In a normal csproj file, the properties for the `Debug|AnyCPU` config are defined like this (1):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Say you want to reuse everything except `DefineConstants`, you create a seperate project file `debug.props` just for defining common properties, put it in the same directory as the project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then it's just a matter of adjusting the main project file to import the common file and set some different values based on configuration. This is done by replacing (1) with this:

```
<Import Project="$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)\debug.props"
   Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug' Or '$(Configuration)'=='MyDebug'" />
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'MyDebug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It should be fairly clear what this does: it imports the file with the common properties (if the config is Debug or MyDebug) then sets different values for DefineConstants depending on which Configuration is used. Since there's now a PropertyGroup for Configuration==MyDebug, VS will recignize this automatically so in the Configuration Manager you can now select `MyDebug` as Configuration. Once you do that, it effects the code like this:

```
#if TRACE //is now only defined for MyDebug config, not for Debug
Console.WriteLine( "hello there" );
#endif
```